# WordPress Multisite for multi-language

Tags: multisite, multi-language

I want to make a WordPress with multiple languages. I have two WordPress sites and I want them to use the same domain name.

Site 1: `http://example.com/en`

Site 2: `http://example.com/de`

Is this possible? What information do I need to search for to find a tutorial.

I don't want to use a plugin like WPML to translate content, I have to use multiple WordPress sites.

Comment: Sure, it is possible and a good choice for a solution with this goal. You can build them without help of plugins, only with the core. If you need more comfort, search for plugins there help you, like MultilingualPress. You should find several how-tos on the web that helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a [standard multisite using the sub-directories option](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bh0qOx9A2FQ) and name your site with the appropriate language slug.

Normally it would be : mysite.com/subsitename
You could just do : mysite.com/en